# How to use the same database connection for multiple methods(JAVA)

Tags: java, database

Hi so I'm starting to learn about database connections in JAVA and I'm developing a mini application which requires a database. I wanted to know what's the proper way of using the the Connection object so that I can use it with multiple methods.

A method to Add a new record, another to search for a specific key and so on.
I will have to access multiple tables each having their own own class and set of methods.

If there's any good book out there about Software Development in JAVA, that might be useful too.

Comment: Sorry, your question in this format is off-topic here because of the rule: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Comment: Please don't repeat the common first-timer mistake of creating a Connection and using it for every query you send to the database.

Comment: what's the correct way then? It's all I'm asking

Answer (score 3):

I think that for simple cases just open and close the connection on each query. For more complicated cases (like a server) you can use connection pool which keeps a list of opened connections

Answer (score 0):

if the application is small you can create a connection object each time you hit the database but if the number of request to the database is pretty high you can use Connection pool  you can use BasicDataSource which is an apache project use singleton pattern to wrapp the instance of basic dataSource and retrieve the connection Object each time you want from that wrapping class
**DataWrapper**

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSourceFactory;

public class DataWrapper {

    private static DataSource datasource;

    private static void initialize() throws Exception {

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testbd");
        props.put("password", "root");
        props.put("username", "root");
        props.put("driverClassName", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        props.put("initialSize", "10");
        props.put("maxTotal", "15");
        props.put("maxIdle", "10");
        props.put("minIdle", "5");
        datasource = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);

    }

    public static synchronized Connection getConnection() throws Exception {
        if (datasource == null) {
            initialize();
        }
        return datasource.getConnection();

    }

}
```

**caller**

```
Connection con=DataWrapper.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement statement=con.prepareStatement("select * from users");

    ResultSet result= statement.executeQuery();
    result.next();
    System.out.println(result.getString(1));
    //dont forget to close the connection object
    con.close();
```